# Other Relationships

Tags: civicase, relationships

I have tried starting over with CiviCase with the new interface as we had not used the XML based configuration.  With the new case type I have a section called *Other Relationships*. The information in this area is wrong and I have no idea where it comes from. I want to make sure that these relationships are not shown or not assigned.  Please help.

[image: Other Relationships Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client's contact summary page, there is a Relationships tab. They come from there. It's intended for relationships that exist outside the scope of the case, like "parent". Whereas a role is a relationship that is just for the lifetime of the case, like case manager.